# proof bonferroni inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

Hi can I ask you if I am doing something wrong with this Bonferroni inequality proof?
So I proved the base case for n=1
$$
 P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{1}F_{i})≥ 1-∑\limits_{i=1}^{1}F_{1}'
$$
which holds always

then I assumed the case for n is true.

Lastly I proved it for n+1
$$
P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}F_{i})≥ 1-∑\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}F_{i}'
$$

The left hand side can be explicited as
$$
P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}F_{i})= P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}\space\  \cap (F_{n+1}))
$$
which can also be rewritten as
$$
1 - P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}’)-P(F_{n+1}’)
$$

then I do the same thing for the right hand side
$$
1-∑\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}P(F_{i}') = 1 - ∑\limits_{i=1}^{n}P(F_{i}') - P(F_{n+1}’)
$$

then rewriting the whole inequality

$$
1 - P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}’)-P(F_{n+1}’)≥1 - ∑\limits_{i=1}^{n}P(F_{i}') - P(F_{n+1}’)
$$
The ones, and the probability of the complement cancel out, as well as the negative signs, and we are left with the original inequality.

It seems quite dubious, so any kind of help is appreciated ;)

Comment: Why is $$
 P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}\space\  \cap (F_{n+1}))
$$
equal to
$$
1 - P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}’)-P(F_{n+1}’)
$$

Comment: I subsituted the 2 members in the parenteses by A and B $$A \cap B$$.And you can find the probability of the intersection by subtractinc from one the probabilities of the complements of the two events.But probably it doesn’t work.Could you explain me why?

Comment: What is the complement of $\cap_{i=1}^{n} F_i$?

Comment: oh, De morgan’s law right?